# Youtube iframe custome controls

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

is there any way to open the video on the website and hide all youtube video controls like(click to play&puse, to press space-bar play&puse, to press m mute, to press up&down key volume up/down) and make my custom video controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use this code to embed YouTube video with keyboard shortcuts disabled and custom button for video controls. And to use more controls and functions, you can read the [YouTube Iframe API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).**
**Note**:Try running this code locally or on third-party compilers like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen), [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) , etc. as Stack Overflow's compiler is facing troubles compiling it.

```js
//YouTube embed with YouTube Iframe API
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// YouTube embed player details
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '668nUCeBHyY',

//Features
playerVars: {
            'controls': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'disablekb':1,
          },
        });
      }
      
//functions
function playYT() {
        player.playVideo();
}

function pauseYT() {
        player.pauseVideo();
}
```

```html
<div style="pointer-events:none" id="player"></div><br><br>
<button onclick="playYT()">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseYT()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Glad, that helped :)